# Configuring colors in Tailwind in Next.js project broke all colors

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS for the first time, and that in a Next.js project. I followed their docs on "how to use tailwind with Nextjs" and tried adding colors in the `tailwind.config.js`, but it ended up breaking all colors. Other styles work.

I watched a YouTube video on Tailwind, but the guy was using it on regular `HTML/CSS` project. He outputted the file in a `public/styles.css` by running `tailwindcss build styles/globals.css -o public/styles.css` but I am using `styles/globals.css` in Next.js by following the docs.

My `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
     //ADDED THIS
      white: {
        0: "#fff",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `theme.colors` to add new colors will fully overwrite the default Tailwind color palette.

Either you define all the colors that you want to use in `theme.colors` explicitly.

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
    //...
    theme: {
        colors: {
            black: colors.black,
            // Define all desired colors
            white: "#fff"
        }
    },
    //...
};
```

Or, if you still want to have access to all the default colors and simply need to extend them, use `theme.extend.colors` instead.

```js
module.exports = {
    //...
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                white: "#fff"
            }
        }
    },
    //...
};
```